# Can adventures be gifted?

Tags: hearthstone

Is it possible and if so how, for *Single Player Adventures* such as *Kharazan* or *The League of Explorers* to be purchased as a digital gift for a friend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to gift adventures digitally but you can purchase a battle.net card and give it.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no.

Had this issue trying to gift this to my girlfriend the other day and found that giving her an App Store gift card was the easiest way.

You could also get them a battle.net gift card but I've found that making the purchase in-app with whatever your phones native payment gateways are is easiest.

Also it's easier to find an apple/Google/whatever card at any grocery store or electronics shop over a battle.net card I've found.